# Azure table query to csv c#

Tags: c#, csv, export, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to write an Azure table Storage Query result to a .csv file and store it locally on the machine (temp is fine). I'm able to query without issue - then display the results in a messageBox. I'm doing this using c#. I don't want to use an external application, but will call on a powershell script if that is what it takes. Ultimately, I'm trying to download the csv so I query the csv file instead of azure tables storage for more functionality. (SQL Server isn't an option at this time - although I do understand it would make my life so much easier)

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse    ("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyStorageAccountNameHere;AccountKey=MyTableKeyhere
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TelephonyIssueLog");

        var managerQuery =  new TableQuery<IssueEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Issues"));
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\csv.csv", managerQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out:
starting with the top

```
    using CsvHelper;





      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstN.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLName.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbDirection.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbPhoneSystem.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustPhone.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtManager.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProgram.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbLocation.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhoneNumber.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbIssue.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbPhoneSystem.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill out the WHOLE Form. Thank you!");

        }
        else
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
               CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=my-account-key
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TelephonyIssueLog");
            //Await is a good command to use here so we don't try to go forward before we verify the table actually exists and error out.
            //Notice I made the function async.  C# is annoying as all out when using async and await so yeah have fun with that :D. -=Chris
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
            IssueEntity IssueLog = new IssueEntity("Issues", lblRandom.Text);
            IssueLog.FirstName = txtFirstN.Text;
            IssueLog.LastName = txtLName.Text;
            IssueLog.CallDirection = cbDirection.Text;
            IssueLog.CustNumber = txtCustPhone.Text;
            //IssueLog.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            //IssueLog.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
            IssueLog.Location = cbLocation.Text;
            IssueLog.Manager = txtManager.Text;
            IssueLog.PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
            IssueLog.PhoneSystem = cbPhoneSystem.Text;
            IssueLog.PrimaryIssue = cbIssue.Text;
            IssueLog.Program = txtProgram.Text;

            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(IssueLog);
            table.Execute(insertOperation);
```

Then, comes the query and CSV Edit:

```
        //get to the cloud storage

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
               CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my-account-name;AccountKey=My-Account-Key
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TelephonyIssueLog");
```

Worked like a charm!

```
        //initiate the writer

        var sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ProgramData\N3RASupportNotifier\Test.csv"); 
        var writer = new CsvWriter(sw);

            TableQuery<IssueEntity> query = new TableQuery<IssueEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Issues"));
        //Write each record to CSV
            foreach (IssueEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
            {
            writer.WriteField(entity.FirstName);
            writer.WriteField(entity.LastName);
            writer.WriteField(entity.Location);
            writer.WriteField(entity.Manager);
            writer.WriteField(entity.PartitionKey);
            writer.WriteField(entity.PhoneSystem);
            writer.WriteField(entity.PrimaryIssue);
            writer.WriteField(entity.Timestamp);
            writer.NextRecord();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple way, I recommend you using a 3rd-party library called [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) to achieve your purpose. After you filtered the data from Azure Table, you could try to add the following code:

```
string csvString = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv<IssueEntity>(managerQuery);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\csv.csv", csvString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little extension to the Azure.Data.Tables SDK to simplify CSV exports that are compatible with Azure Storage Explorer:

```cs
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV;

TableServiceClient tableServiceClient = new(connectionString);
TableClient tableClient = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient("tablename");

// Export all rows from the table to a CSV file
using StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Export all rows as CSV to Azure BLob Storage
BlobContainerClient containerClient = new(BlobConnectionString, "testcontainer");
var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("test.csv");
var stream = await blobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true, new BlobOpenWriteOptions() { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/csv" } });
using StreamWriter writer = new(stream);
await _tableClient.ExportCSVAsync(writer);

// Import all rows from a CSV file to the table
using StreamReader reader = new("test.csv");
await _tableClient.ImportCSVAsync(reader);
```

[Source](https://github.com/ThomasPe/Azure.Data.Tables-Extensions#csv-export--import) [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.CSV/)